# Applications using Java Collections

Tags: java, collections, skip-lists, concurrentskiplistmap

Is there a way to find some Java application that uses
a specific collection. I implemented my own concurrent skip list
and wanted to "replace" it into an application where `ConcurrentSkipListSet` of
Java collections is used to see the performance difference of my implementation
and `ConcurrentSkipListSet`.

I know that I could benchmark both skip lists implementation (mine and Java's) but I would like to see what's the difference in a real scenario.

Any ideas on how to find such an application? (*I searched inside the Java standard library but couldn't find anything using `ConcurrentSkipList`).

Comment: @FredericClose, thanks for the suggestion. Actually I already tried googling `"ConcurrentSkipListSet" site:github.com` but didn't find anything important. With grepcode it seems I only find the already implemented `CocnurrentSkipListSet` implementation and nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

You can use GitHub's code search.

https://github.com/search?l=java&q=ConcurrentSkipListSet&ref=cmdform&type=Code